# Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\apply\insert.php on line 11
>       Database not selectedNot inserted

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to server';
}

if (!mysql_select_db($con,'staff'))
{
    echo "Database not selected";
}

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else {
    echo 'Inserted';
}

header("refresh:2; url=index.html");

?>
```

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. Change above to `mysqli_select_db($con, 'staff');`

Comment: Also: it should be `mysql_select_db('staff', $con)`

Comment: @Arnauld - He should **not** use `mysql_select_db()` at all since he's using `mysqli` and you should not use both extensions at the same time.

Comment: @Cyclone Sorry for the laconic and ambiguous comment. It was certainly not intended as a fix. My point was just to explain the nature of the error message mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions.

Change `if (!mysql_select_db($con,'staff'))` to `if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'staff'))`

Comment: For some reason now when i insert data the error doesnt appear anymore, but it displays "not inserted".what could be the problem here? @The Codesee

Comment: Under `echo 'not inserted';` put `echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));` and then let me know the error it displays

Answer (score 0):

write your code like below:

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'staff'))
{
    echo "Database not selected";
}

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else {
    echo 'Inserted';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write your code like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','staff');
if (!$con)
{
echo 'connection not established';
}

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))

{
echo 'Not inserted';
}

else {
echo 'Inserted';
}
```